# Creating draggable dynamic items

Tags: qml, qtquick2, qtreeview

I have a menu with grouped components (qtreeview). I want to drag them into another treeview.

The treeview

```
    TreeView {
         id: menuView
         Layout.minimumWidth: 50
         Layout.fillHeight: true
         rowDelegate: Item {
              height: 30
         }
         height: parent.height
         property int dragItemIndex: -1
         itemDelegate:  dndDelegate
         model: myModel
         onCurrentIndexChanged: console.log("current index", currentIndex)
         TableViewColumn {
              title: "Name"
              resizable: false
         }
     }

    /*Delegate for displaying treeview item*/
    Component  {
         id: dndDelegate
         Item {
              DraggableArea{}
         }
    }

    /*Draggable area*/
    MouseArea {
        id:mouseArea
        onPressed: Code.startDrag(mouse);
        onPositionChanged: Code.continueDrag(mouse);
        onReleased: Code.endDrag(mouse)
        anchors { left: parent.left; right: parent.right }
        height: dragRect.height
        width:dragRect.width
        drag.target: dragRect
        Rectangle {
            id: dragRect

            Image {
                id: menuItemImage
                anchors.leftMargin: 5
                anchors.left:parent.left // set anchor to be able to set margin
                anchors.verticalCenter:parent.verticalCenter
                source:model ? model.CommandIcon:""
            }
            Text {
                anchors.left:menuItemImage.right
                anchors.verticalCenter:parent.verticalCenter
                text:model ? model.CommandTitle:""
                anchors.leftMargin: 5
                font.pixelSize: 14
            }

            width: menuView.width - 50
            color: "red"
            border.color: "black"
            border.width: 2
            radius: 4
            height: 27

        }
    }
```

and the javascript code to drag by copying the items

```
var itemComponent = null;
var draggedItem = null;
var startingMouse;
var posnInWindow;

function startDrag(mouse)
{
    posnInWindow = dragRect.mapToItem(root, 0, 0);
    console.debug("posnInWindow: "+ posnInWindow.x + " " + posnInWindow.y);
    startingMouse = { x: mouse.x, y: mouse.y }
    console.debug("startingMouse: "+ startingMouse.x + " " + startingMouse.y);
    loadComponent();
}

//Creation is split into two functions due to an asynchronous wait while
//possible external files are loaded.

function loadComponent() {
    if (itemComponent != null) { // component has been previously loaded
        createItem();
        return;
    }

    itemComponent = Qt.createComponent("../DraggableArea.qml");
    if (itemComponent.status == Component.Loading)  //Depending on the content, it can be ready or error immediately
        component.statusChanged.connect(createItem);
    else
        createItem();
}

function createItem() {
    if (itemComponent.status == Component.Ready && draggedItem == null) {
        draggedItem = itemComponent.createObject(root, {"x": 40,
                                                     "y": posnInWindow.y});

        draggedItem.anchors.left = undefined;
        draggedItem.anchors.right = undefined;
        console.debug("draggedItem created: "+ draggedItem.x + " " + draggedItem.y);
        // make sure created item is above the ground layer
    }
    else if (itemComponent.status == Component.Error) {
        draggedItem = null;
        console.log("error creating component");
        console.log(itemComponent.errorString());
    }
}

function continueDrag(mouse)
{
    if (draggedItem == null)
        return;

    draggedItem.x = mouse.x + posnInWindow.x - startingMouse.x;
    draggedItem.y = mouse.y + posnInWindow.y - startingMouse.y;

    //console.debug("mouse: "+ mouse.x + " " + mouse.y);
    //console.debug("posnInWindow: "+ posnInWindow.x + " " + posnInWindow.y);
    //console.debug("startingMouse: "+ startingMouse.x + " " + startingMouse.y);
    //console.debug("draggedItem: "+ draggedItem.x + " " + draggedItem.y);
}

function endDrag(mouse)
{
    draggedItem.destroy();
    draggedItem = null;
}
```

The problem is that these dynamically created items aren't perceived as draggable (I just emulate dragging changing coordinates in JS). How to do it right, like it works in QTreeView approach? Setting *drag.target* for newly created object doesn't seem to work (get an exception)